# JRuby 1.6.3 upgrade to Rails 3.1 has broken migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, jrubyonrails

I have recently upgraded my gemfile to try and get Rails 3.1 working with Jruby 3.1.

Here is my Gemfile:

source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.engineyard.com'

```
gem 'rails',               '~> 3.1.0.rc4'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'compass', :git => 'https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git', :branch => 'rails31'
gem 'fancy-buttons'
gem 'haml'
gem 'authlogic', :git => 'https://github.com/AndreasWurm/authlogic.git'#, :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'bundler'
gem 'resque'              
gem 'resque-meta'        
gem 'jquery-rails'     
gem 'rake'#, '~> 0.8.7'          
gem 'eventmachine'
gem 'em-websocket'
gem 'json'
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'

platforms :jruby do
    gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
    gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
    gem 'jruby-openssl'
    gem 'jdbc-mysql'
    gem 'jruby-rack'
    gem 'warbler'
    #gem 'glassfish', '1.0.3.dev'
end

group :test, :development do
  platforms :jruby do
    gem 'jdbc-sqlite3', :require => false
    gem 'fastercsv'
    gem 'ruby-debug'
  end

  platforms :ruby do
    gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  end

  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'fakeweb'
  gem 'shoulda', :require => 'shoulda'
end
```

The problem is that when I run rake db:migrate, I get the following error message:

> rake aborted! An error has occurred, this and all later migrations
>   canceled:
>
> undefined method `rows' for nil:NilClass

Has anyone else experienced this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to rails 5 enabled my migrations to build from jruby 1.6.3 anyway:

source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.engineyard.com'

```
gem 'rails',               '~> 3.1.0.rc5'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'compass', git: 'https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git',branch: 'rails31'
gem 'fancy-buttons'
gem 'haml'
gem 'authlogic', :git => 'https://github.com/AndreasWurm/authlogic.git'#, :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'bundler'
gem 'resque'              
gem 'resque-meta'        
gem 'jquery-rails'     
gem 'rake'#, '~> 0.8.7'          
gem 'eventmachine'
gem 'em-websocket'
gem 'json'
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'

platforms :jruby do
    gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
    gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
    gem 'jruby-openssl'
    gem 'jdbc-mysql'
    gem 'jruby-rack'
    gem 'warbler'
    #gem 'glassfish', '1.0.3.dev'
end
```